# How many kebab menus (more options menus) can you fit in on one screen?

Tags: navigation, menu, web, contextual-menu

I have just joined a new project and designed a part of the interface where users can see original text and translated text side by side.

The app itself has a top bar with Logo, Profile, More Options and Settings items. The part of the interface I designed also contains the More Options menu, under which I hid additional options, which will not be used too often.

The Stakeholder said that this cannot be done because there are too many "More options" or "Context" menus on the screen, and he would prefer that those two options are somewhere on the interface, visible at all times. One of them is the Download Translated Document option, and the other is Change Target Language.

I want to keep the interface clean and keep labels that are easy to understand. The stakeholder is extremely hard to convince. So tell me, please, how bad is that there are two "Context menus" on the screen? [image: Interface screen shot with two context menus]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with multiple "overflow menus" is that the user will constantly have to remember which action is stored in which menu. They are correct for hiding less-used functions, but they are probably not the ideal place for settings such as choosing a language. If your users are doing a "set it and forget it" approach to the target language, you might want a cog icon vs. a "kebab" to let the user know that's where they can make configurations. If they are changing the language frequently, you might want to make that a UI button.

"Download translated document" seems like it would be highly useful for some users, even if it's not widely used by all. Consider adding it as a secondary button with a download icon in the same location as the overflow menu next to the toggle buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The 'kebab' menu, Google's Material Design language, is designed to open smaller inline menu items. If possible hiding the menu items are not considered a good UX practice. In your design, it seems that there is enough space to accommodate the mentioned items.

Anyway, you have settings and a kebab at the top bar. Then it is a case of accommodating one more icon. Please see the design attached, is this will make sense for you? Also, clicking on the profile picture will navigate to the profile details.

[image]

Comment: The place where you put the icons is a totally different context, I would say. The bar that is below (the one with three buttons) is the one that pertains to the translated documents context.